# Possibility of Synchronized and Exactly Same Multiple Sites via WordPress Multisite

Tags: multisite

I did read the documentation and I believe that I couldn't find this information there. I would like to know that if it is possible that I can have multiple site's content (pages, posts and all the database stuff) fully synchronized, such that all posts, pages CRUD in one site, leads to changes in the other sites. Only things that I don't need synchronized is:-

1. Site specific CSS (which is resolved, thanks to wp stackexchange.)
2. Site specific sub domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find the [ThreeWP Broadcast plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/threewp-broadcast/) useful. It takes care of "broadcasting" new posts/pages and updates to them to (any or all) sites in a WordPress MultiSite installation. It has a lot of add-on plugins that extend its functionality even further.